# How to achieve the same result for a function without using loops, arrays, strings, and lists?

Tags: php, function

For starters, i'm new in PHP.

I have the function, that prints a row of numbers from 1 to **$nums**.
But my task is not allows me to use loops, lists, arrays, and strings.
So how can I achieve the same result without using these?
I really do not know, though i tried.

```
function returnString($nums) {
    $error = "Error!";
    $str = "";
    if ($nums > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nums; $i++) {
            $iter = $i + 1;
            $str .= $iter . PHP_EOL;
        }
        return $str;
    }
    else {
        return $error;
    }
}

$numString = returnString(30);

echo $numString;
```

Also, range() is not allowed too, because it's creates an array from range. Maybe i can create a counter, that increments number from 1? Like **$num = 0 $num + 1**. I need your advice how can i pull this off, guys.

Thanks, any help will be immeasurable!

Comment: Your task excludes everything that you should be using, especially strings unless you just want to return numbers.

Comment: The only solution I can think is making `returnString()` a recursive function.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can you show me how can i "just return numbers" from 1 to $nums? What do you mean? If this is not so difficult, use the code example to show what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If strings are allowed for transfer, then **recursion** is a solution:

```
function returnString($nums) {
    if ($nums<=0)
        return '';
    return returnString($nums-1) .$nums.PHP_EOL;
}

$numString = returnString(30);

echo $numString;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that first return not make the 2nd one execute?

Comment: The return only executes if $nums equals to zero. This is the termination condition.

Comment: No the first return is only the termination for $nums==0. Try it out: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d8f5e4d5cdbb6aa78a964cdc0cc4a327b700ab3

Comment: @Sascha Ok. I just thought that from what [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) on `return` states: *"If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file."* - Just curious.

Comment: @Sascha Wow, good solution for that! But can you tell me, why we return returnString( $nums-1) with **$nums-1**? What did it mean? If i just use nums it says: **Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)**

Comment: @Slayer598 which number did you input for nums?

Comment: That's right but the return is only executed if and ony if the condition is true. For better readability I could write also  `if ($nums===0) return ''; else return returnString($nums-1) .$nums.PHP_EOL;`

Comment: @Slayer, @ Sebi2020 - For every number greater 0 this behaviour is normal if  `returnString($nums)` is called because than there is no termination and it will loop inifinite.

Comment: @Sebi2020 For example, 60. If function return itself with parameter **$nums** -1 - it works well, but with just **$nums** parameter it says:  **Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)**. Why it working like that?

Comment: @FunkyFortyNiner _"return statement immediately ends execution"_ ... if reached. But in this case it is reached only when $num==0.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I only saw your message to me because I am still in the question/answer. I didn't get the ping because you added another character to my name, being "Funky" instead of "Funk". Reason why I asked about the 2 returns was for `return '';
    return returnString($nums-1) .$nums.PHP_EOL;`. I guess I am not grasping how returns work then.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner - For a one-liner you could left the curly brackets away, I could write also: `if ( ..) { return '' } else { return ...}` to make it clear.

Comment: @Sascha Ok thanks. I'll have to read up on `return` more and try some stuff, *cheers* :)

Comment: @Slayer598 `$num-1` is necessary to make the function call itself (see [recursion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) ) with a smaller and smaller number until the exit condition (`$num===0`) is met.

Comment: @Sascha you already got my +1, but I suggest adding a guard check for negative `$num`s that would make diverge the algorithm.

Comment: I added it though it is not necessary because OP says `prints a row of numbers from 1 to $nums.` that sounds for me for $nums is a positive integer.

Comment: @Sasha missed that the TO wanted to replace `$nums-1` by `$nums`